# Prevent Input field to lose focus

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is an example of code with an input field that is inserted as a component, each change in the input field loses focus. It seems that when you change the whole component is re-rendered, and those losing focus, what is the best practice for implementing a dynamic form like this, and how to prevent loss of focus here?

PS: This is a small example of a part of a more complex form, where each subsequent part of the form depends on the choice of the previous one.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-react-spring-svg-parallax-rxmr8)

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const SELECT_UPDATED = 'INPUT_UPDATED'
const TEXT_UPDATED = 'TEXT_UPDATED'
const TEXT_UPDATED2 = 'TEXT_UPDATED2'
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  selectedType: '',
  inputText: '',
  inputText2: ''
}

let reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_UPDATED:
      return { ...state, selectedType: action.selectedType }
    case TEXT_UPDATED:
      return { ...state, inputText: action.inputText }
    case TEXT_UPDATED2:
      return { ...state, inputText2: action.inputText2 }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE)
  console.log('state: ', state)

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={[{ value: 'edit_text', label: 'Edit text' }, { value: 'hide_input', label: 'Hide input' }]}
        onChange={e => dispatch({ type: SELECT_UPDATED, selectedType: e.value })}
      />
      <p/>
      <SecondStep />
    </div>
  )

  function SecondStep() {
    if (state.selectedType === 'edit_text') {
      return <div>
        <input type="text" autoFocus value={state.inputText} onChange={e => dispatch({ type: TEXT_UPDATED, inputText: e.target.value })} />
        <input type="text" autoFocus value={state.inputText2} onChange={e => dispatch({ type: TEXT_UPDATED2, inputText2: e.target.value })} />
        </div>
    } else if (state.selectedType === 'hide_input') {
      return <div>Hidden input</div>
    } else {
      return <div>NA</div>
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use autoFocus attribute to your input like this

```
<input type="text" autoFocus value={state.inputText} onChange={e => dispatch({ type: TEXT_UPDATED, inputText: e.target.value })} />
```

**Update**

I just changed your code, below I have used here 3 input box

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const SELECT_UPDATED = 'INPUT_UPDATED'
const TEXT_UPDATED = 'TEXT_UPDATED'
const TEXT_UPDATED1 = 'TEXT_UPDATED1'
const TEXT_UPDATED2 = 'TEXT_UPDATED2'
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  selectedType: '',
  inputText: '',
  inputText1: '',
  inputText2: '',
  autoFocus1:true,
  autoFocus2:false,
  autoFocus3:false,

}

let reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action.type)
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_UPDATED:
      return { ...state, selectedType: action.selectedType }
    case TEXT_UPDATED:
      return { ...state, inputText: action.inputText, autoFocus1:true, autoFocus2:false, autoFocus3:false }
    case TEXT_UPDATED1:
      return { ...state, inputText1: action.inputText1 , autoFocus1:false, autoFocus2:true, autoFocus3:false }
    case TEXT_UPDATED2:
      return { ...state, inputText2: action.inputText2 , autoFocus1:false, autoFocus2:false, autoFocus3:true }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, INITIAL_STATE)
  console.log('state: ', state)

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={[{ value: 'edit_text', label: 'Edit text' }, { value: 'hide_input', label: 'Hide input' }]}
        onChange={e => dispatch({ type: SELECT_UPDATED, selectedType: e.value })}
      />
      <SecondStep />
    </div>
  )

  function SecondStep() {
    if (state.selectedType === 'edit_text') {
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" autoFocus={state.autoFocus1} value={state.inputText} onChange={e => dispatch({ type: TEXT_UPDATED, inputText: e.target.value })} />
          <input type="text" autoFocus={state.autoFocus2} value={state.inputText1} onChange={e => dispatch({ type: TEXT_UPDATED1, inputText1: e.target.value })} />
          <input type="text" autoFocus={state.autoFocus3} value={state.inputText2} onChange={e => dispatch({ type: TEXT_UPDATED2, inputText2: e.target.value })} />
        </div>
      )
    } else if (state.selectedType === 'hide_input') {
      return <div>Hidden input</div>
    } else {
      return <div>NA</div>
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: If there are two Input fields it's always focused to the second one, then what should be the right solution? Code updated

Comment: @Pumych try to add autoFocus to the one you wish to stay focused on rerender?

Comment: @Pumych if you have two input try to add autoFocus to the 1st one, if you put autoFocus to every input it will focus on the last one by default, you may programmatically assign this autoFocus to your desired input, but make sure there is only one autoFocus at a time

Comment: @tareq if I put "autoFocus" only on first input it always focused on the first input. How do I add/remove the autoFocus programmatically in my code?

Comment: Yes, initially it will focus on 1st input, later if u try to type on 2nd one focus will move to the 2nd one and keep it there until you move

Comment: @tareq I see in code that this behaves in other way, the focus always returned to the first input field

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is about re-rendering, you can assign key values to components so that components that are deemed to stay after state update won't be unmounted / remounted again.

Comment: can you please show an example on regarding the current code?